# Customize javafx checkbox (center text and markbox)

Tags: java, javafx-8

Im building a small programm with javafx without scenebuilder, but styling with css.

I have a VBox in a VBox with several checkboxes. The checkboxes are rearangeable via drag and drop. Thatswhy I need to give them a backgroundcolor. But unfortunately this looks like this:
[image: checkboxes with backgroundcolor]

The text and the markbox are not centered verticaly, as i want them to.

I tried textalligment, alligment and workarounds with labels but the result is allways the same, not centered.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

EDIT: My code (without actionlisteners and style):

```
VBox checkBoxBox = new VBox(5);
    checkBoxBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

    for (Kind kind:kinds) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(kind.description());
        cb.setSelected(kind.visible());
        cb.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        checkBoxBox.getChildren().add(cb);
    }
```

This "produces" the 5 checkboxes. The VBox is inside another VBox together with the button. If you need editional code please comment again ;)

Comment: Looks like a padding issue to me, but it's hard to know without looking at code. Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RonSiven: ty, while trying to build this example, I found the problem! To style the checkbox exactly like my buttons I added the style "button" to them, which I had defined myself in the Style.css. Don't know how(yet) but this arranged the checkbox not centered in the larger space.